# Writing $3p$ when $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ as a sum of two rational cubes. Is this result new? And what about its converse?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

I recently discovered a proof of the following. Let $p$ be a prime that's $1 \bmod {3}$. Suppose that $p$ is not represented by the principal quadratic form $(1,9,81)$ of discriminant $-243$ (The first three $p$ that are represented by this form are $61$, $67$, and $73$). Then neither $3p$ nor $3p^2$ is a sum of two rational cubes.

The proof is elementary (at the undergraduate level) in the following sense. In the statement of the theorem I impose two further conditions  on $p$, each of which like the non-representability by $(1,9,81)$ is easily checked for any given $p$. The first of these supplementary conditions in fact holds for all $p$, while the second (that $3$ is not a cube in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$) is equivalent to $p$ not being representable by $(1,9,81)$. But the assertions of this last sentence are cubic reciprocity results authored by Eisenstein and  Gauss.

**Question 1**

In view of this last paragraph, my result could have been proved even as early as the time of Gauss. But I think it may be new - I've seen no reference in Sylvester. Does anyone have a historical reference?

**Question 2**

When $p$ is $61$, $67$ or $73$, then $3p$ is indeed the sum of two rational cubes. So it's natural to ask whether the converse to my theorem holds. When $p$ is represented by $(1,9,81)$ is it true that $3p$ and $3p^2$ are sums of two rational cubes? This has something of the flavor of Sylvester's question about representing primes congruent to $4$, $7$ or $8 \bmod{9}$ (and their squares) as sums of two rational cubes. Before the work of Elkies, Dasgupta-Voight and Kriz which (I hope) have settled the question there was $3$-descent work by Selmer that "reduced" things to the parity conjecture. What does the approach of Selmer reveal here? And has anyone looked at the elliptic curves explicitly, and tried to use the Heegner point approach to produce solutions to the equations?

EDIT:

Though my result is not new, some may like the proof I give---it appears as Theorem 2.3 (and its corollary) of my arXiv submission [arXiv:2309:00162](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.00162)

(I don't now how close to the argument of Sylvester and Pepin my argument is).

Comment: Dear Paul Monsky: although it does not answer directly your question, you may want to have a look at closely related elementary results of mine (joint) at arXiv:0903.4963v3. Of course Noam Elkies is the person to answer.

Comment: Dear Henri Cohen: Thanks for referring me to your article. I've written up a set of undergraduate classroom notes on the sum of two cubes problem, giving what I think are the cleanest proofs of various results of Euler, Legendre, Kummer and Sylvester and going on to a few (new?) results like the one I cited. My handwriting is a bit sloppy, but if you'll provide a postal address, I'll put a copy in the mail to you. There are puzzling questions about the representations of various sorts of Eisenstein integers that I hope a computer expert can throw light on.---Paul Monsky

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For question 1.

The condition $p$ is represented by $(1,9,81)$ or equivalently by $(1,1,61)$ is equivalent to the condition that  $p\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $3 \mod p$ is not a cube (this is exercise 9.10 in Cox's book 'Primes of the forms...').
And Satge's paper 'Groupes de Selmer et corps cubiques' already proved under this condition, neither $3p$ nor $3p^2$ is a sum of two rational cubes.

For question 2.

I checked using Sagemath that for $p=61,67,73,103,151,193,271$ the rank of the related elliptic curve of $3p$ is 2 while for $p=307$ the rank is 0. So the converse is not true. Similar thing also occurs for $3p^2$. However for $p\equiv 2,5\mod 9$, it is proved that $3p$ and $3p^2$ are both sums of two cubes by constructing the Heegner point in the paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00208-022-02370-3.pdf

Comment: [Satgé's paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82070149.pdf)

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: yhb---I looked at Satge's paper where he proves a more general result where instead of a single p that's 1 mod 3 you have a product of such p, and reciprocity conditions are imposed. What he says about the significance of having many p makes me suspect that I was actually rediscovering a result of Selmer---Satge speaks about Chapter IX, Theorems VIII and IX of Selmer's opus. The opus is too daunting for me, but are my suspicions correct?

Comment: I have a look at Selmer's opus, but I can not see Chapter IX, Theorems VIII and IX implies the result directly. Instead, 9.2.3 in Selmer's opus may suggest this result is already proved by Sylvester and Pepin. But I do not check Sylvester and Pepin's paper.

Comment: @yhb  I edited my question a day ago but someone removed my edit. Indeed Selmer explicitly says on page 301 that the result in question was proved by Sylvester and Pepin. I assume their proof, like the most complete form of my proof makes use of cubic reciprocity. In any case my proof will be up on arXiv shortly, so you or anyone interested can compare the arguments.Thanks for finding the reference in Satge, and for the counterexample to my suggested converse.

Comment: @paul Monsky Dear Paul, you are welcome. By the way I want to comment that representing primes congruent to $4$, $7$ or $8$ mod $9$ as sums of two rational cubes is still open now. The only known results with proof now is Dasgupta-Voight and the result in the paper https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2022-375-04/S0002-9947-2021-08556-6/home.html